# Is it possible to get the url of the customer who uses our Web Service SOAP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm new to SOAP, I work with PHP5 and I got my wsdl file with some functions in my .php file. I'm wondering if I can get the url from the customer who uses my Web Service. I want to validate the url in a php function server-side.

Comment: Which URL do you want to get from the customer?

Comment: The page where he uses the code : $sClient = new SoapClient(...);

Comment: How do you even know that SOAP client comes from a webpage?

Answer (score 0):

In your server you can try to get $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] or $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] but i'm not sure if it will help you a lot.

Like Bruno said, sometimes your client don't comes from a webpage.

Comment: For my project I know the client will come from a webpage, but I tryed the two PHP commands, REMOTE_ADDR work, but HTTP_REFERER return an empty string.